# R: ifelse on string

Tags: string, r, if-statement

I am populating a new variable of a dataframe, based on string conditions from another variable. I receive the following error msg:

`Error in Source == "httpWWW.BGDAILYNEWS.COM" | Source ==  : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types`

My code is as follows:

`County <- ifelse(Source == 'httpWWW.BGDAILYNEWS.COM' | 'WWW.BGDAILYNEWS.COM', 'Warren',
ifelse(Source == 'httpWWW.HCLOCAL.COM' | 'WWW.HCLOCAL.COM', 'Henry',
ifelse(Source == 'httpWWW.KENTUCKY.COM' | 'WWW.KENTUCKY.COM', 'Fayette',
ifelse(Source == 'httpWWW.KENTUCKYNEWERA.COM' | 'WWW.KENTUCKYNEWERA.COM', 'Christian')
)))`

Comment: You need to make a comparison after every `|`. For example, `ifelse(Source=='foo1' | Source=='foo2', return1, return2)` instead of `ifelse(Source=='foo1' | 'foo2', return1, return2)`

Comment: Yeah, you're right & I missed a few comparator conditions which is why the code failed. Nevertheless, I should try a cleaner technique...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you break down that deeply nested `ifelse` statement into more manageable chunks.

But the error is telling you that you cannot use `|` like that.  `'a' | 'b'` doesn't make sense since its a logical comparison.  Instead use `%in%`:

```
Source %in% c('htpWWW.BGDAILYNEWS.com', 'WWW.BGDAILYNEWS.COM')
```

I think... If I understand what you're doing, you will be much better off using multiple assignments:

```
County = vector(mode='character', length=length(Source))
County[County %in% c('htpWWW.BGDAILYNEWS.com', 'WWW.BGDAILYNEWS.COM')] <- 'Warren'
etc.
```

You can also use a `switch` statement for this type of thing:

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  switch(x,
         'httpWWW.BGDAILYNEWS.COM'='Warren',
         'httpWWW.HCLOCAL.COM'='Henry',
         etc...)
}
```

Then you want to do a simple apply (`sapply`) passing each element in `Source` to `myfun`:

```
County = sapply(Source, myfun)
```

Or finally, you can use `factors` and `levels`, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader...

Comment: +1 for `switch`. If you find yourself using more than 2 `ifelse`'s, you should probably be using `switch` or `cut`.

Comment: @Justin, sorry to ask but can you post a more specific example for the `switch` function? Specifically, how do I create the `County` variable from the `Source` variable using `switch`? Much agreed that my `ifelse`s are not parsimonious.

Answer (score 6):

A different approach:

```
county <- c("Warren","Henry","Fayette","Christian")
sites <- c("WWW.BGDAILYNEWS.COM","WWW.HCLOCAL.COM","WWW.KENTUCKY.COM","WWW.KENTUCKYNEWERA.COM")
County <- county[match(gsub("^http","",Source), sites)]
```

This will return `NA` for strings that do no match any of the given inputs.

Using Hadley's suggestion ([lookup-tables-character-subsetting](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Subsetting#lookup-tables-character-subsetting)):

```
lookup <- c(WWW.BGDAILYNEWS.COM="Warren", WWW.HCLOCAL.COM="Henry", WWW.KENTUCKY.COM="Fayette", WWW.KENTUCKYNEWERA.COM="Christian")
County <- unname(lookup[gsub("^http","",Source)])
```

Comment: You could also eliminate the `match` and use character subsetting directly: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Subsetting#lookup-tables-character-subsetting