# switch function for column values

Tags: r, switch-statement

I have a variable of initials, with names erroneously scattered throughout the list. See example structure below:

```
ID <- c('SPW', 'SM', 'DLS', 'SJ', 'joe.schmoe', 'CEJ', 'teddy.roos', 'GVF', 'MJC',  
        'LH', 'sally.fields') ## Full names shouldn't be there -- only initials.
test <- data.frame(ID)
```

I want to create a new variable (ID2), that switches out any names with assigned initials. Otherwise, I want ID2 to contain the initials from ID. An example of my currently unsuccessful code will hopefully illustrate:

```
swfun <- function(x) {
    switch(x,
        'joe.schmoe' = 'JS',
        'teddy.roos' = 'TR',
        'sally.fields' = 'SF',
        as.character(test$ID)
        )
    } ## In other words, I've created a switch function to replace any names   
              ## with requisite initials. I was 'hoping' that the last command   
              ## [as.character(test$ID)] would populate the rest of ID2 with values 
              ## from test$ID.
test$ID2 <- sapply(test$ID, swfun)
```

Rather than getting `test$ID2 <- c('SPW', 'SM', 'DLS', 'SJ', 'JS', 'CEJ', 'TR', 'GVF', 'MJC', 'LH', 'SF')`,

I'm getting `test$ID2 <- list(NULL, NULL, "TR", NULL, c("SPW", "SM", "DLS", "SJ", "joe.schmoe", "CEJ", "teddy.roos", "GVF", "MJC", "LH", "sally.fields"), "JS", 
    NULL, "SF", NULL, NULL, NULL)`

This question is similar to one I asked previously ([R: ifelse on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866281/r-ifelse-on-string)), however with the added variation of populating the rest of the column with values of the previous column. Additionally, I'd like to solve this using `switch` since I'm still fairly new to that function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I switch on a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just switch that last line in the switch function to use `x` instead of `test$ID`

```
swfun <- function(x) {
    switch(x,
        'joe.schmoe' = 'JS',
        'teddy.roos' = 'TR',
        'sally.fields' = 'SF',
        as.character(x)
        )
    }
```

---

#### Results

```
> unname(sapply(ID, swfun))
 [1] "SPW" "SM"  "DLS" "SJ"  "JS"  "CEJ" "TR"  "GVF" "MJC"
[10] "LH"  "SF"
```

**Edit re Vectorize (Frank):** If you find yourself `sapply`ing this often, you might consider

```
swfun2 <- Vectorize(swfun)
unname(swfun2(ID))
 [1] "SPW" "SM"  "DLS" "SJ"  "JS"  "CEJ" "TR"  "GVF" "MJC"
[10] "LH"  "SF"
```

or the alternative linked in the comments below.

Comment: You could also use `swfun <- Vectorize(...` and then use `swfun(ID)` directly.

Comment: @Frank, I wouldnt use `switch` at all, I would just used a named vector. Much easiier

Comment: Ok. These days I tend to make a labeled list or character vector, take `data.frame(names(x),x)` and merge it in, filling in a default value at the end.

Comment: @Frank... I dont follow.  What is the advantage/utility there?   What could you do with the data.frame that you could not already do with `x`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm just saying that's what I do...it's an alternative, but I don't have an argument for it beyond that it's no-frills and thus fairly easy to maintain. Merging is simpler for me to understand than lapply with names or whatever. Also, a data.frame is easy to read when printed. Alternately, it's pretty easy to just `read.table(text=...`, with space-separated pairs on each line, and then merge that in. Anyway, probably off-topic here.

Comment: @Frank I've never used Vectorize before & just now looking @ the documentation, could you post a small example or reference?

Comment: @DaNiu, there was a question on SO some while back on how to vectorize which offered a good explanation of the function

Comment: @DaNiu I've edited a reply into this answer, but Ricardo can remove it if desired.

Comment: nah, @Frank, thats great